# Updating database object in Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-admin

I am making a Django project where the user uploads their picture, and it gets saved in the database. And if the user uploads the same picture multiple times on the same day, it uploads the existing field, rather than creating a new one. My error is that while it updates the existing field, it also creates a new one. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
if img == None:
        messages.error(request, "Please submit an image.")
        return render(request, 'page.html')
elif Image.objects.filter(user=user, date=today).exists():
        image_file_like = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(img))
        a=str(uuid.uuid4())
        image = Image(user=user)
        image.img.save(f"{a}.png", image_file_like, save=True)
        path = f"media/{a}.png"
        toUpdate = Image.objects.filter(user=user, date=today) 
        toUpdate.update(img = path)
        print('works2')
        return render(request, 'page.html')
else:
        image_file_like = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(img))
        a=str(uuid.uuid4())
        image = Image(user=user)
        print('works3')
        image.img.save(f"{a}.png", image_file_like, save=True)
        image.save() 
        return render(request, 'page.html')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both of your if statement blocks have the same image saving code, regardless of whether an image already exists or not - this is the culprit:

```
 image = Image(user=user)
 image.img.save(f"{a}.png", image_file_like, save=True)
```

This code also doesn't add 'today' to the Image, is that set as `auto_now_add` on your model? If not then the if-statement comparison will always fail.